Finding cost of CHI gas token over a series of time
so I wanted to use a database I have to find the cost of the CHI gas token over a series of time. I got all the pools that have a CHI gas token, and I get data1 / data0 from all the sync events in that pool to get the price. I have a few questions:

Is doing data1/data0 correct?
What currency is this division giving me? Ether?
Does anyone have any idea how I could convert it to USD given the conversion rate is constantly changing?

